# Canvas object as thumb in SeekBar, Test align. Android

Tags: android, text, paint, alignment, android-canvas

I have a problem with set up the right position of the text as a paint in canvas object,
which I use as thumb in customise SeekBar.

```
public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text)
{

     Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
     bm.setDensity(165);
     Paint paint = new Paint();      
     paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
     paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 

     paint.setTextSize(size);
     paint.setTypeface(my.b1);
     paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
     canvas.setDensity(165);
     canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

     return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
}
```

There is a circle with current progress. So the text is 
dynamic cause can be from 2 characters ("0-9%") to
4 characters ("100%"). Also the problem is not only with position,
but also with the size of the text.

[image]